# The same function for iterable obects and non iterable objects

Tags: python, function

Is the right way to encapsulate non-iterable object in collection to make the same interface for iterable and non iterable objects?

```
import collections

def function(item):
    if not isinstance(item, collections.Iterable):
         item = [item]
    process_collection(item)
```

*The question is not dedicated to find out ways of determining if object is iterable, it is dedicated to find out the rightness of wrapping the non iterable object into a collection to use the same code for iterable and non iterable objects.*

Comment: Yes, that's a good way.

Comment: Thank you for answer! :)